# unable to get expected result shell array

Tags: bash, ksh

```
#!/bin/sh
NR=0
getent passwd | while IFS=':' read USERNAME PSSWD MY_UID MYGID GECOS HOMEDIRS SHELLS
do
users[$NR]=$USERNAME
((NR++))
done
echo "${users[*]}"
```

if I execute above with `ksh` replacing `sebang` it works, but with bash it does not.

Comment: use `while ... done < <(getent passwd)`

Comment: I would have used `while ... done < /etc/passwd`, but the last comment of @Andrea Corbellini is better. For the ignorants like me that don't know this type of statement, look in the bash man page for `Process substitution`

Comment: If you've got Bash 4.2 or later, you can get the same behaviour as `ksh` by setting the `lastpipe` option: `shopt -s lastpipe`.

Answer (score 1):

Both **sh** and **bash** create a subshell after the pipe.

In other words, **while** block inherits the variables from the parent shell but modification won't affect the variables in the parent shell.

**ksh** is not creating a subshell, so it is working.

In my tests, the script provided does not run in pure **sh**.

A simple **sh** solution would be to use **/etc/passwd** directly:

```
#!/bin/sh --
NR=0
users=""
while IFS=':' read USERNAME PSSWD MY_UID MYGID GECOS HOMEDIRS SHELLS ; do 
  users="${users} ${USERNAME}" 
  NR=$(expr "${NR}" + 1) 
done < /etc/passwd
printf "%s\n" ${users}
```

There is below a solution using bash (with @pjh hint):

```
#!/bin/bash --
NR=0
passwdentries="$(getent passwd)"
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    exit 1
fi
while IFS=':' read USERNAME PSSWD MY_UID MYGID GECOS HOMEDIRS SHELLS ; do 
   users[$NR]=$USERNAME 
   ((NR++)) 
done <<<"${passwdentries}"
printf "%s\n" ${users[*]}
```

In order to illustrate this subshell situation, the version below prints all the users, but still the values of the variables are unchanged in parent shell (with @glennjackman hint):

```
#!/bin/bash --
NR=0
getent passwd | (
  while IFS=':' read USERNAME PSSWD MY_UID MYGID GECOS HOMEDIRS SHELLS ; do
    users[$NR]=$USERNAME
    ((NR++))
  done
  printf "%s\n" ${users[*]}
  )
```

Comment: There is a very serious problem with process substitution: it's impossible to get the exit status of sub-processes.  A useful alternative is to put the command output in a variable and then take input from the variable: `getent_output=$(getent passwd) ; IFS=: read ... ; do ... ; done <<< "$getent_output"`.

Comment: Nice. In the last one, the line continuations are not required: it's OK to have a multi-line script within parentheses.

Comment: @pjh true, the answer had been updated, thx!

Comment: @glennjackman true! the answer had been cleaned up, thx!

Comment: @all : thanks for your answers.